# Instrumentation : Profiling within LINQ operator?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015, profiling

I'm trying to profile a fairly large application and for a certain time in the process a lot of the time spent is in logic within LINQ operators.

I'm using instrumentation (i need as close as possible to line level cpu usage everywhere) and have my executable and dll selected. However when i get to the methods i'm mentioning i have a large % of cpu time in LINQ operators and i don't get to see that % of the time detailed within it as the operator itself isn't in the profiling scope (not defined in those dlls but in the Framework).

Exemple :

```
void MyMethod()
{
     var result = SlowMethodDefinedInThisDll1(); // This will be reported fine in the profiler as well as the detail of SlowMethodDefinedInThisDll1
     // Will be reported as source code not available for Any in the profiler
     var sampleQuery = [SomeLargeDataSet]
         .Any(item=>item.SlowMethodDefinedInThisDll2()); // SlowMethodDefinedInThisDll2 as well as whatever happens within won't be reported
}
```

Is there any way to do what i desire while keeping instrumentation level of detail in visual studio?